# I need to resize an array of pointers

Tags: c++

Lets say i want to resize an array of int pointers, i have a function that looks like this

```
    template<typename T>
static void Resize(T* arr, UINT oldsize, UINT newsize) {
    T* ret = new T [newsize];
    memcpy(ret, arr, sizeof(arr[0]) * oldsize);
    delete[] arr;   
    arr = ret;
};
```

The problems begin when i try and resize an array of elements that were created with the "new" keyword (even though the data itself inside the class is POD) because the delete[] triggers their deconstructor which then leaves the new array with pointers to objects that dont exist anymore. So.. even though the objects were created with "new", cant i just use the free command to get rid of the old array? or somehow delete the array without triggering the deconstructor of each member?

Comment: This would work fine if `arr` was declared `T*& arr` (assuming `T` is trivially-copyable and has a `noexcept` default constructor).

Comment: If you are going to be writing potentially dangerous code like this then just use `malloc` and `free`. Your code cannot handle non-trivial types because of the `memcpy` so there's not much point in using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Pubby: Or we can suggest `std::copy` so that it's done properly, rather than _more improperly_.

Comment: `the delete[] triggers their deconstructor which then leaves the new array with pointers to objects that dont exist anymore` - No; the `delete[]` destroys the original pointers, not the `int`s they pointed to.

Comment: Just for clarity, Jake. Are you saying you're using this to manage an array of `int*`. I.e. an in the case you're talking about T is `int*` and thus `arr` is `int**`? is that accurate?

Comment: I switched to vectors, was easier then i thought. Also got to cut out 3/4 of my code since apparently most of it was spent on managing arrays T_T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `std::vector`.

---

**EDIT**: by popular demand, an explanation of why the OP's code *does not work*.

The code:

```
template<typename T>
static void Resize(T* arr, UINT oldsize, UINT newsize) {
    T* ret = new T [newsize];
    memcpy(ret, arr, sizeof(arr[0]) * oldsize);
    delete[] arr;   
    arr = ret;
};
```

Here `arr` is a pointer passed by value. Assigning to `arr` at the end only updates the local copy of the actual argument. So after this the actual argument, in the calling code, points to an array that has been `delete`d, whith pretty catastrophic result!

It could be sort of rescued by passing that pointer *by reference*:

```
template<typename T>
static void Resize(T*& arr, UINT oldsize, UINT newsize) {
    T* ret = new T [newsize];
    memcpy(ret, arr, sizeof(arr[0]) * oldsize);
    delete[] arr;   
    arr = ret;
};
```

But this is still pretty fragile code.

For example, the caller needs to keep track of the array size.

With a `std::vector` called `a`, the resize call would instead look like

```
a.resize( newSize )
```

and in contrast to the DIY solution, when `newSize` is larger, those extra elements of the vector are nulled (which is a bit safer than leaving them as indeterminate values).

A `std::vector` can be indexed just like a raw array. See your **C++ textbook** about more details of how to use it. If you don't already have a C++ textbook, do get one: for most people it's just an impractical proposition to learn C++ from articles and Q/A on the web.

Comment: Ok, I'm a new downvoter and here's why I gave you -1; you didn't answer the question.  This is obviously someone without much experience, perhaps a beginner.   "Use a vector" is garbage advice in and of itself because *it does not help the OP understand how his code works*.  I don't want to work with people who don't understand how pointers and dynamic memory allocation work because they were always told to "use a vector".  It is good advice (with an explanation) to be given *after* you answer the question, but you should answer the question first.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  All I'm saying is that I see advice like "use a vector" handed out to beginners without an explanation far too often.  They need to understand *why* you would use a vector over an array in the first place, what problems it solves, etc.  Without understanding why the abstraction exists in the first place they're just writing cargo cult code and will never be able to tackle truly difficult, lower level problems in their software.

Comment: @Ed.S educating you about how to best educate programmers, in the space available here, is not something i would attempt. you can start by reading beginner's books such as bjarne stroustrup's latest, or koening and moo's accelerated c++. according to you their approach, using containers such as `std::vector`, is "garbage advice". i think that **even you** must understand that you can't be right when the language's creators see it totally differently, but you will have to delve into the matter on your own to understand just how misguided your view is.

Comment: Alf vs. the world. Again. Don't you get tired of this?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't know if you're an extremely stubborn, arrogant guy or beeing hacked by a troll. If you insist on _that_ beeing a "perfect" answer, you're very wrong. If you add a good explanation why the OP should switch to a std::vector it would be tolerable to ignore the fact that you didn't even try to answer the actual question.

Comment: @ildjarn: what's the point of that ad hominem argument (it's a well known fallacy, you know), if you had any valid technical argument?

Comment: Exactly my point -- I'm not _making_ an argument, merely an observation that every post you make seems to invite hostility. You took that observation and turned it into some sort of accusation. Amazing.

Comment: @stefan: the OP has not asked about any explanation of his code. his own explanation of his code is **self-contradictory**, involving "deconstructors" being invoked by clearing or deleting an array of pointers. you have either not read, or not understood, the question.

Comment: @ildjarn: what's the point of the *second* ad hominem argument from you? you're on a roll, OK. but perhaps you could calm down a little.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Quoting from the OP: "i want to resize an array of int pointers". I think that makes it very clear that he doesn't use a std::vector and looks for a solution for his problem with _pointers_. I didn't say that std::vector isn't a solution, it surely is! But in this form, it is an extremely bad answer and nonetheless doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: I'm anything but upset, Alf – your posts make for an entertaining spectacle almost every single time. ;-]

Comment: Dowvote removed and an added +1 now that you have added an explanation of *why* the original code was wrong.  So much more helpful for someone who is stumped.

Comment: Haha .. even _I'm_ not this bad! Please look up the meaning of _ad hominem_: it does not apply to every scenario in which someone, in isolation and with no particular goal, makes an observation about your behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, what you're trying to do isn't a terribly bad thing, and there are times it makes sense, but it's simply not supported by the interface provided by `new` and `delete` (or `new[]` and `delete[]`).  As others have said, it **is** supported by `malloc`, `free`, and `realloc` (with the caveat that `realloc` will copy the pointer values on reallocation, but won't guarantee that the pointers in the new area are initialized to anything useful, like `NULL`).

So, without further ado, the easiest answer that will work for almost everybody is to use a `std::vector<int>` instead of trying to manage the memory yourself.  The vector has the ability to resize, and when it does it will copy things that need copying.  `std::vector` exists to provide a "resizable array" and manage the memory for you.  Actually, if you want a container of pointers, you're best off using either a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`/`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` (in C++11) or something from [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

For what it's worth, the original STL did not use `new[]` or `delete[]` to implement `std::vector<T>`.  Often, the operating system gives far more memory than you ask for.  For instance, if I try to `malloc` 16 bytes, the block I get back may well be 1024 bytes.  I can use that to store four 32 bit integers.  When I run out of space, I may ask for 32 bytes, and get a different block of 1024 bytes, which I can copy my four integers to.  But why go through the trouble of asking for a new block to hold my integers, when the original block was actually large enough to begin with?  Unfortunately, `new[]` and `delete[]` don't provide a way to say "give me a block that's at least this large, and by the way here's a block that might already be big enough."  `realloc` kind of does.  [Facebook Folly includes a `std::vector`-like container](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/FBVector.h) that doesn't use `new[]` or `delete[]` (note that it doesn't use `realloc` either, because that usually won't work with containers of objects; instead it uses `malloc` and the non-standard function `malloc_usable_size`), and [Firefox goes through the trouble](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2011/08/05/clownshoes-available-in-sizes-2101-and-up/) to manage memory in a similar manner.

Even so, I would discourage trying to get tricky.  `std::vector` has a lot of satisfied users.

Answer (score 1):

I think that making all elements in array point to NULL before deleting should do the job. But if you can use STL then std::vector would make your life much easier (as Alf suggested :P).

Comment: The problem i have with this is that i have a class A, i cant seem to add std::vector<A*> to the class, it says "no members defined using this type"

Comment: @JakeFreelander, you'll need to show us some code on your efforts to use `std::vector<A*>` as a member.  It certainly can be done, so it's simply a question of getting the syntax right.

Comment: i got it working, im new to vectors though, do i need to delete the vector in deconstructor?

Comment: @JakeFreelander:  no, you don't need to delete the `std::vector`.  It will destry itself when it falls out of scope.